# json Fetch rerun

Tags: flutter, dart

So i'm writting app in which i fetch data from air quality index webpage [www.waqi.info](https://waqi.info)   and display it. So i got it working for one city but when i change city on popuplist how to recall api with different url. Tried something but it doesn't work. Now i have idea to save city in phone memory and then reruning app. Any clues how i can recall Http request for different city almost same url but how to recall http request from onchange. Im new to flutter and dart. Sorry for any stupidty

Comment: Welcome to SO. We need some code to get started.

Comment: show your code first, what you have done so far.

Comment: [code](https://pastebin.com/nqu0d4dM) here you go

Comment: [new](https://pastebin.com/aQRzEtie) got it working again for one city called getData but screen numbers doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `http 0.12.0+2` library to do API calls [http library page](https://pub.dev/packages/http)
you can simply create a function which will fetch data

```
getData(city) async{
  String url="YOUR_URL_HERE?city="+city;
  var response=await http.get(url);
  return response.body;
}
```

You can call this method from your `onChanged`

Comment: nosuchmetod error The method [] was called on null
[code](https://pastebin.com/nqu0d4dM)

Comment: [new](https://pastebin.com/aQRzEtie) got it working again for one city called getData but screen numbers doesn't change

Comment: You have to change the screen number with `setState((){})`

Comment: [code](https://pastebin.com/NFvnPPFC) so i called it but it doesnt work... it changes value for popupbutton but for api fetch it says nosuchmetod... like there isnt any data there

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function to call api and pass city name as argument

like this

```
callApi(city) async{
String url="Url/${city}";
var response=await http.get(url);
return response.body;
}
```

and after getting response set data drom response to model object and then call setState()

which will reset your whole screen

Comment: i don't get where i need to put it

Comment: You have to call this method for calling the api everytime

Comment: this is method to call api please put it in your state class

Comment: [code](https://pastebin.com/NFvnPPFC) so this is onchange and it outputs me NoSuchMetod error The method [] was called on null.

Comment: Its working im dumb for others city API data is different a bit so it gives me null ....